# matplotlib y tkinter para graficar en tiempo real

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, matplotlib, animación

Estoy tratando de graficar una serie de datos de un archivo de texto, pero mi idea es que esta grafica solo aparezca cuando oprima un boton en una GUI hecha en tkinter. Sin embargo, en el momento de oprimir el boton aparece la grafica pero sin los datos, osea aparece en blanco.

Bueno les dejo mi codigo y espero que me puedan ayudar:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.animation as animation
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk

    class ini():
        def __init__(self):
           self.fig = plt.figure()
           self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
           self.datosy=[]
           self.datosx=[]

        def animada(self):
           datostext = open('datos.txt','r').read()
           lines = datostext.split('\n')
           for line in lines:
              if len(line)>1:
                 self.x, self.y = line.split(",")
                 self.datosx.append(self.x)
                 self.datosy.append(self.y)
          self.ax1.clear()
          self.ax1.plot(self.datosx,self.datosy)


        def fungraf(self):
           self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, 
                                          self.animada,   #serias dudas aca  
                                          interval=1000)    
           plt.show() 



    h=ini()
    raiz=Tk()
    raiz.geometry("600x600")

    boton=ttk.Button(raiz,text="start",command=h.fungraf)
    boton.pack()


    raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok estuve buscando varios codigos de ejemplo y no me habia fijada que la funcion animada o mejor dicho la funcion que actualiza los datos de la grafica, necesita un parametro ("i") que indica el numero del cuadro de animación, corrigiendo la funcion quedaria así:

```
    def animada(self,i):    #aqui es donde agrego la i
       datostext = open('datos.txt','r').read()
       lines = datostext.split('\n')
       for line in lines:
          if len(line)>1:
             self.x, self.y = line.split(",")
             self.datosx.append(self.x)
             self.datosy.append(self.y)
      self.ax1.clear()
      self.ax1.plot(self.datosx,self.datosy)
```

ok entiendo que la solucion era bastante sencilla, sin embargo si alguien en algun momento llega a tener el mismo problema, espero que esto le pueda servir.